# How do I authorize my device for ADB if I have only the recovery installed (no ROM)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, side-loading

I'm using a Nexus 5 (hammerhead) and was running CyanogenMod 13. I used CyanogenMod Recovery to wipe /data and /system, but to sideload a different ROM, a quick Google search told me I needed to update adb on my Ubuntu 14.10 install.

However, after updating adb to 1.0.32, doing `adb devices` shows my phone as unauthorized, and thus I cannot flash, push or sideload to the device whatsoever. I can't authorize it either, because I have no Android or CyanogenMod on the device to receive the authorization request.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Simple - ditch CM recovery and go TWRP.

Comment: I can't flash a new recovery without adb being authorized for my device. Using `fastboot flash twrp.img` only gets me a `<waiting for device>` until I terminate the command.

Comment: That only means you should sort out issues with your fastboot driver...

Comment: Where do you suppose I start?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I managed to figure it out. I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that fastboot requires the phone to be in the bootloader, not recovery. I was able to flash a new recovery using `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`.

Comment: Derp, that was an unexpected mistake... Glad you sorted it out though :)

Comment: I further ran into an issue (which might have been the biggest problem to begin with), where a partially incomplete wiping of `/system` and `/data` prevented me from properly mounting either. Reformatting them fixed the issue, and I was able to then sideload my ROM. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.